# How do you ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a user info without breaking the database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple table with students in MySQL database. Similar to:

| student_id | student_name | teacher_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Adam | 100 |
| 2 | Bob | 100 |
| 3 | Carl | 100 |
| 4 | Dan | 200 |

Teachers can input new students or change existing student's names. Currently I have this set up to update via:

```
INSERT INTO student_list (name) VALUES (:name) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE student name= values(name)
```

The problem is that this completely breaks any associated student_ids in other tables (as the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE changes the student_id). I could look up each entry before updating, but it seems messy. Surely there's a better way.

```
CREATE TABLE `sabrep_db`.`students` ( `student_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `name` TEXT NOT NULL , `teacher_id` INT NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`student_id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `students` (`student_id`, `name`, `teacher_id`) VALUES (NULL, 'Adam', '100'), (NULL, 'Bob', '100');
```

Comment: Please edit the question and define which database this is for. It also helps to post a complete repro (table creation, data insert, decription if actual outcome, description of required outcome). I'm not familiar with the syntax, but since you're only appearing to update the name, I don't understand why it would change an existing id.

Comment: Can you explain the behavior of the test case you don't like?  This created nothing unusual.  There was no update behavior.   Two rows were inserted with a unique primary key.  The only way to update a student name is to either `UPDATE` directly or to `INSERT` using an existing `student_id`.  If you simple `INSERT` with a `name` and no explicit `student_id`, you get a new `student_id` which touches no existing students.  You have a different problem you didn't mention, that a `name` is not unique.  If that's an issue, you need to handle that case with at least a unique constraint.

Comment: Your question doesn't describe SQL that does what you're worried about.  The `INSERT INTO students (name) VALUES (:name) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE student name= values(name);` doesn't (can't) change the primary key at all.  This kind of `INSERT` just creates a new primary key based on auto_increment behavior.  I'm not sure what `student_list` is.  That might be a typo in the question.  Adjust the question to contain a test case that exhibits the behavior you don't like.

Answer (score 0):

Should also pass a key (usually the primary key) as part of the insert so that it knows the key reference to update when there is a duplicate, name is passed twice for the update portion:

```
INSERT INTO student_list (student_id, name) 
VALUES (:student_id, :name) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE student_name = :name;
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be really unsafe? A malicious teacher could manually change the student

Comment: Is `or change existing student's names` not an update?